# jQuery .each() repeating the answer for all rows

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which sort of works, with the exception that I get the same answer repeated on all row.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>each demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span>(click here to change)</span>
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pn">84ps01</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pn">92K002</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pn">68F017</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    var pn = $("#pn").text();
  $( "td#pn" ).each(function() {
      $(".div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))
  });
  });

</script>
 $(this).("#div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+pn+"#result");
</body>
</html>
```

`data.asp` is a simple page that queries a database using `request.querystring("prodref")` to return a result.

So I am trying to get each row of the table to query the database and return the result.

Comment: here `$(".div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))` you're loading the data into every element that has a class of `div1`, on each iteration of the `.each()` function.  This isn't jQuery's fault, jQuery is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ID Should be unique, Different HTML Elements can not have same ID**, use class for that.

```
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="pn">84ps01</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="pn">92K002</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="pn">68F017</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "td.pn" ).each(function() {
      $(this).next().load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))
});
```

You were getting the same answer because `id` refers to the first matched element always.

And use `.next()` to go the next sibling of the current element.

Comment: Try the updated code. Use `.next` to address `.div1`

Answer (score 1):

when you load the data with the line

```
$(".div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()))
```

you'll see that you are loading the last result in each of the `td` with class `div1` (that's why you see the same thing in each row).

what you need to do *instead* is to find just the corresponding `div1` of each row and insert the data in.

the solution will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "span" ).click(function() {
        var pn = $("#pn").text();
        $( ".pn" ).each(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find(".div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+($(this).text()));
        });
    });
});
```

what the above code is doing, is finding each `.pn` and iterating through them (`.each()`), then finding the `.closest()` `tr` traversing up the DOM tree, finding the `.div1` within that specific `tr`, and then loading the result into it.

also, as an fyi, `id`s are supposed to be unique, so you should switch `id="pn`
 to `class="pn"`

```
<tr>
    <td class="pn">68F017</td>
    <td class="div1">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```